# Rotating a small image on a background image places the small image in the wrong location

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const cCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  cCanvas.width  = 600;
  cCanvas.height = 300;
const cContext         = cCanvas.getContext('2d');
const cBackgroundImage = new Image();
const cBackgroundWidth = cCanvas.width;

let lBackgroundHeight;
const cCarImage       = new Image();
const cCarImageWidth  = 40;
const cCarImageHeight = 100;
let lCarTopLeftX;
let lCarTopLeftY;

document.addEventListener(
  'DOMContentLoaded', (ev) => {
    cBackgroundImage.onload = function() {
      cCarImage.onload = function() {
        const cAspectRatio = cBackgroundImage.naturalWidth / cBackgroundImage.naturalHeight;
        lBackgroundHeight = cCanvas.height = cBackgroundWidth / cAspectRatio;
        cContext.drawImage(cBackgroundImage, 0, 0, cBackgroundWidth, lBackgroundHeight);
        lCarTopLeftX = cBackgroundWidth / 2 - cCarImageWidth / 2 + 70;
        lCarTopLeftY = lBackgroundHeight / 2 - cCarImageHeight / 2 + 100;
        //Note: lCarTopLeftX = 350
        //Note: lCarTopLeftY = 321.869
        cContext.drawImage(cCarImage, lCarTopLeftX, lCarTopLeftY, cCarImageWidth, cCarImageHeight);
      }
      cCarImage.src = "Car.jpg";
    }
    cBackgroundImage.src = "Streets.jpg";
  }
)
document.body.addEventListener(
  "keydown", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    render();
  }
)

function render() {
  //Note: lCarTopLeftX = 350
  //Note: lCarTopLeftY = 321.869
  cContext.clearRect(0, 0, cCanvas.width, cCanvas.height);
  cContext.drawImage(cBackgroundImage, 0, 0, cBackgroundWidth, lBackgroundHeight);
  let lRadians = Math.PI / 180 * 0; // let lRadians = Math.PI / 180 * 45;
  cContext.translate(lCarTopLeftX, lCarTopLeftY);
  cContext.rotate(lRadians);
  cContext.drawImage(cCarImage, -cCarImageWidth / 2, -cCarImageHeight / 2, cCarImageWidth, cCarImageHeight);
  cContext.rotate(-lRadians);
  cContext.translate(-lCarTopLeftX, -lCarTopLeftY);
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="520"></canvas>
</div>
```

-- This code puts a car on a street background. Pushing a key on the keyboard rotates the image.

The plan was to rotate the car 45 degrees.  Because of the strange result, the angle has been changed to 0 degrees to help debug.

The car and background images --- Car.jpg => https://snipboard.io/ptkWjJ.jpg --- Streets.jpg => https://snipboard.io/4YgDaf.jpg.

The images combined --- https://snipboard.io/IXlKiV.jpg.

The image after hitting the keyboard spacebar --- https://snipboard.io/QTBlgS.jpg.  --- The car moved to a different location, even though X and Y did not change --- lCarTopLeftX = 350 --- lCarTopLeftY = 321.869

Comment: Any rotation is carried out from an axis... ask yourself the question of its position in relation to your image (no, it is not in the center).  And please read **carefully** this : [use a real and minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Mister Jojo, It's not reproducible?

Comment: in the case of computer code everything is always reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had assumed that “context.translate” uses the X Y of the image top left corner, as “context.drawImage” does. Incorrect!

The “context.translate” does use the X Y of the image “center”.

Solution:

```
  let lCarCenterX = lCarTopLeftX + cCarImageWidth / 2;
  let lCarCenterY = lCarTopLeftY + cCarImageHeight / 2;
  ...
  cContext.translate(lCarCenterX, lCarCenterY);
  ...
  cContext.translate(-lCarCenterX, -lCarCenterY);
```